# LuaJIT FFI not loading symbols from executable

Tags: c, lua, shared-libraries, ffi, luajit

First Lua code:

```
local ffi = require "ffi"

ffi.cdef[[
void printc(const char *fmt, ...);
]]
ffi.C.printc("Hello world")
```

Does not work. Error:

```
boot.lua:6: /usr/lib64/libluajit-5.1.so.2: undefined symbol: printc
```

However, the symbol is in fact defined inside the executable that LuaJIT is running from (and the function declaration is copy-pasted from C):

```
$ nm --defined-only build/a.out | grep printc
00000000000650c1 T printc
```

My first idea for a solution was to build a shared library with the same symbols as the executable and load it in LuaJIT:

```
$ cc -fPIC -shared $LDFLAGS $OFILES -o build/a.so
```

New Lua code:

```
local ffi = require "ffi"
lib = ffi.load("./build/a.so")
ffi.cdef[[
void printc(const char *fmt, ...);
]]
lib.printc("Hello world")
```

This allows me to call the `printc` function. However, there's a very big issue: **the loaded library uses a separate memory space from the running program.** The buffer that `lib.printc("Hello world")` is writing to is not the same buffer as the program that LuaJIT is running in uses. It acts as if it's interacting an entirely different process.

`printc` is supposed to print to the console subsystem of the executable that LuaJIT is running inside of. The console buffer is stored as a global (`extern`) array of strings, which `printc` writes to. The global console buffer that LuaJIT gets by loading `a.so` points to some other memory address than global console buffer of the running `a.out` program.

So that is not a viable solution. I don't know what I'm supposed to do now. The symbols are being exported as part of my executable but LuaJIT not loading them. I can't `ffi.load` my executable either:

```
lib = ffi.load("./build/a.out")

boot.lua:2: ./build/a.out: cannot dynamically load position-independent executable
```

How can I get the LuaJIT FFI to load symbols from my running executable?

Comment: Not an expert, but try `objdump -t ./build/a.out` and see if the symbol even exists in the executable :)

Comment: You probably need to export symbols from the executable by using `-Wl,-E` when linking.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer that's what `nm --defined-only does`. Here is `objdump -t  build/a.out| grep printc`: `000000000001abd1 g     F .text 0000000000000179              printc`

Comment: The suggestions to use `-E` didn't work, but it led me to finding the `-rdynamic` flag which did fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the `-rdynamic` flag to `cc` fixes the issue, allowing LuaJIT to run `ffi.C.*` functions from the program.

Comment: For something approaching a TL;DR rationale for this answer, ^F https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html for "export-dynamic". gcc passes this option to ld(/collect2) during linking when -rdynamic is specified.